# How to avoid static query in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

In a function, I need an array of values which is a result of a simple query like:

```
SELECT array_agg( some_col ) FROM some_table;
```

I could declare it in function like:

```
my_array text[] := SELECT array_agg( some_col ) FROM some_table;
```

But:

- this dataset changes maybe once in some years
- this dataset is really small
- this function would be called a lot
- this dataset needs to be up to date

Is there a way to avoid executing the same query over and over? It is not particularly expensive to call, but due to its static nature, I'd like to avoid it.

I could set trigger on `some_table` to generate the cached version of `my_array` on any mutation on the table, but is there a way to hold such a variable all the time for every connection?

I'd like to write this function in SQL or PLPGSQL.

Comment: *"It is not particularly expensive to call, but due to its static nature, I'd like to avoid it."* sounds like premature optimization to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres you can create materialized views ([see the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html)). It allows you to store the result of a query, and refresh it whenever you want.

It acts like a virtual table, so it is very cheap to query against.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mymatview AS SELECT array_agg( some_col ) FROM some_table;
```

And when you want to refresh it:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mymatview;
```